# Correctly resolve a `node_module` inside .flowconfig

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, webpack, flowtype

I have webpack `aliases` set up in my webpack config:

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
      styles: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/styles/'),
      utils: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utils/')
    }
```

I also have `[options]` set up in my `.flowconfig` to account for this (so that I don't get `Required module not found` errors everywhere):

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*

[include]

[libs]
./libdefs.js


[options]
esproposal.class_static_fields=enable
esproposal.class_instance_fields=enable
esproposal.decorators=ignore
module.name_mapper='^components\(\/?.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/components/\1'
module.name_mapper='^styles\(\/?.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/components/styles/\1'
module.name_mapper='^utils\(\/?.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/utils/\1'
```

I get no flow errors for standard imports from `node_modules`, like `import moment from 'moment'`. However, when I try and import from within a `node_module` like so:

```
import _uniqueId from 'lodash/uniqueId'
import classNames from 'classnames/bind'
```

I get the old error:

```
yarn run v0.20.3
$ "/Users/rorysmith/code/gen/node_modules/.bin/flow" 
src/components/Calendar.jsx:4
  4: import _times from 'lodash/times'
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lodash/times. Required module not found

src/components/Calendar.jsx:5
  5: import _uniqueId from 'lodash/uniqueId'
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lodash/uniqueId. Required module not found

src/components/Calendar.jsx:7
  7: import classNames from 'classnames/bind'
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ classnames/bind. Required module not found

src/components/Category.jsx:16
 16: import _uniqueId from 'lodash/uniqueId'
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lodash/uniqueId. Required module not found
```

How can I resolve this so that the error doesn't show?

Comment: Try using `module.system.node.resolve_dirname=node_modules`